# Javascript display image from uri

Tags: javascript, html, image, load, uri

As part of Javascript code, after getting the uri, I tried to get an image from that uri, and insert it into a cell at the beginning of a row. Below is my code. It doesn't work. I couldn't figure out what I've done wrong/ how to achieve this. Do I need to use a XMLHttpRequest() or can I just create an image with source uri? Can someone please help? Many thanks in advance! I commented in the code as well.

```
    var rowx =document.getElementById(rowid); //get that row that I want to insert image
    var x =rowx.insertCell(0); //insert a cell
    var uri= "baseuri"+rowid; //this is the uri where I get the image from 
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.scr= uri;
    x.appendChild(img); //I tried x.innerHTML = img, but that didn't work either
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I noticed is you have `img.scr` instead of `img.src`.

Comment: Gosh that's such a stupid mistake. Thank you mate!! I spent like an hour on this. I will accept your answer after a few mins